# How to rank these functions in increasing order of complexity [Algorithms]?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I have the following functions:

[image]

1. What is the correct order of these functions in increasing complexity?
2. I could always start entering values in these functions and check the corresponding output to notice the rate of increase. But is there a better, faster way of ranking these functions in order of increasing complexity? For example are there rules of thumb I could use to quickly sort these in order of increasing complexity? (Like I know generally exponential functions are more complex than log functions)

Comment: Have you heard of asymptotic notation, and in particular of big-Oh notation? I have a feeling that you may not.

Comment: Approach 2 is badly flawed. Finite samples *never* prove asymptotics! It can be useful to form hypotheses, though.

Comment: Be careful with the use of the term "complex" here. Are you comparing the asymptotic growth of the functions lists, or the "complexity" of computing them?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it after understanding asymptotic notation and the complexity of some common functions. Here's the order from least expensive to most expensive:

> log log n, log n ~ ln n, (log n)^2, sqrt(n), n, n log n, n^(1+x), n^2,
>   n^3, n-n^3+7n^5, 2^(n-1) ~ 2^n, e^n, n!

Comment: How/why did you rank $\log n$ vs $\ln n$? Or $2^{n-1}$ vs $2^n$?

Comment: They are both equal. I edited my post to reflect that now.

Comment: They are clearly not *equal*.

Comment: I thought they were nearly equal in terms on asymptotic growth? Our teacher asked us to indicate when 2 functions were asymptotically equal.

Comment: Asymptotically equal w.r.t $\Theta$ or $\sim$ or ... ? ("$=$" typically means *exact equality* so you don't want to use that symbol.)